# Using Stripe Upcoming Invoice to preview changes in subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to use [Stripe Upcoming Invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) to display how much a user will be billed when he makes changes to his subscriptions. But it seems that I miss something...

### Why do I get 29 instead of 0?

```php
dump($plans['basic_monthly']->price);
```

```
29.0
```

```php
dump($plans['premium_monthly']->price);
```

```
49.0
```

```php
$stripe_customer = step1_create_customer();
$stripe_subscription = step2_create_subscription($stripe_customer, $plans['basic_monthly']->stripe_price_id);

dump([
    'reason' => 'Nohting was changed (price_id and quantity are the same), so 0 is expected. Why 29 is here?',
    'expected' => 0,
    'actual' => upcoming($stripe_subscription, $plans['basic_monthly']->stripe_price_id)->amount_due/100,
]);
```

```
array:3 [▼
    "reason" => "Nohting was changed (price_id and quantity are the same), so 0 is expected. Why 29 is here?"
    "expected" => 0
    "actual" => 29
]
```

```php
dump([
    'reason' => 'Transition to more expensive plan was made. 49 - 29 = 20 is expected',
    'expected' => 20,
    'actual' => upcoming($stripe_subscription, $plans['premium_monthly']->stripe_price_id)->amount_due/100,
]);
```

```
array:3 [▼
    "reason" => "Transition to more expensive plan was made. 49 - 29 = 20 is expected"
    "expected" => 20
    "actual" => 20
]
```

```php
function step1_create_customer()
{
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));

    $test_clock = $stripe->testHelpers->testClocks->create([
        'frozen_time' => time(),
        'name' => sprintf('Testing Upcoming Invoices'),
    ]);

    $stripe_customer = $stripe->customers->create([
        'test_clock' => $test_clock->id,
        'payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa',
        'invoice_settings' => ['default_payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa'],
        'metadata' => [
            'testing_upcoming_invoices' => 1,
        ],
        'expand' => [
            'test_clock',
            'invoice_settings.default_payment_method',
        ],
    ]);

    return $stripe_customer;
}

function step2_create_subscription($stripe_customer, $stripe_price_id)
{
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));

    $stripe_subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
        'items' => [
            [
                'price' => $stripe_price_id,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ],
        ],
        'metadata' => [
            'testing_upcoming_invoices' => 1,
        ],
    ]);

    return $stripe_subscription;
}

function upcoming($stripe_subscription, $stripe_price_id)
{
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));

    $stripe_invoice = $stripe->invoices->upcoming([
        'subscription' => $stripe_subscription->id,
        'subscription_items' => [
            [
                'id' => $stripe_subscription->items->data[0]->id,
                'price' => $stripe_price_id,
                'quantity' => 1,
            ],
        ],
        'subscription_cancel_at_period_end' => false,
        'subscription_proration_behavior' => 'always_invoice',
        //'subscription_proration_date' => $now,
    ]);

    return $stripe_invoice;
}
```

Comment: don't forget there is wallet(credit) for each customer. make sure to check in stripe account for better understanding each transaction process. look for invoice (sub total, total, applied balance, amount due)

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing here is upgrading a Subscription from Price A ($29/month) to Price B ($49/month) immediately after creation. You're also passing `subscription_proration_behavior: 'always_invoice'`.

When you upgrade or downgrade a subscription, Stripe calculates the proration for you automatically. This is something Stripe documents in details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade) and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations).

In a nutshell, since you move from $29/month to $49/month immediately after creation, what happens is that Stripe calculates that:

- You owe your customer credit for the time they paid on $29/month that they won't use. Since it's immediately after creation, you owe them $29.
- The customer owes you for the remaining time for the new Price. Since it's the start of the month they owe you the full price of $49.

In a default integration, the proration is created as 2 separate InvoiceItems that are pending until the next cycle. In your case you pass `proration_behavior: 'always_invoice'` so an Invoice is created immediately with only those 2 line items. -$29 + $49 = $20 which is where the amount comes from.

Comment: That's correct. But the question was different. Why I get 29 instead of 0 when "upgrading" from Plan A (29/month) to Plan A (29/month)? What I expected is 0, what I got is 29. Upgrading from Plan A to Plan B works just fine.